# Why does validates_associated save a parent with an invalid child?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This rails app is saving invalid parents/children when using a non-crud action, but raising the appropriate errors when using normal crud actions.

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :locations
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations
  validates_presence_of :locations
  validates_associated :locations
end
```

...

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :job
  validates_presence_of :job
  has_many :line_items
  accepts_nested_attributes_for_line_items
  validates_presence_of :line_items
  validate :comments_if_any_line_items_skipped
private
  def comments_if_any_line_items_skipped
    if line_items.present? and line_items.where(skipped: true).present?
      errors.add(:reason, 'cannot be blank if any line items are skipped?') if comments.blank?
    end
  end
end
```

...

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @job = Job.new(job_params.merge(started: Time.now))
    if @job.save
      redirect_to perform_job_url(@job)
    end
  end
  def stop
    @job = Job.find(params[:id])
    if @job.update(job_params.merge(stopped: Time.now))
      redirect_to @job
    end
  end
end
```

Jobs get created with locations and line items pre-populated and a start time automatically saved, but the locations' comments are blank and the line items' skipped defaults to false. On the job's perform page a form where comments can be recorded and line items can be marked as skipped is available. When the form is saved, the job's stop time is recorded along with the associated locations' and line items' attributes.

For whatever reason, no matter how I write the code, the job will update it's stop time if the location is in an invalid state (no comment while skipped line items are present).

It seems to me that the `validates_associated :locations` line in the job model should prevent this.

Another point to note: The jobs controller has perfectly normal edit/update actions where the job cannot be saved if the associated location is in an invalid state.